# Bare minimal Chef provisioning and deployment?

Tags: chef, chef-solo, knife

I've read the documentation on Chef twice over. I still can't wrap my head around it's concept because they skip but fundamentals and jump to complex deployments with chef-server.

Using chef-solo and possibly knife, is there a simple way to provision a server and deploy?

I may be wrong, but it seems like with my cookbooks prepped, this should be *very* simple.

```
knife rackspace server create --flavor 1 --image 112
```

That provisions my server. I can optionally pass --run-list "recipe[mything]", but how do my cookbooks in ~/my_cookbooks actually get on the server? Do I have to manually transfer them? That seems counterproductive.

Comment: You mean _one_ server? Don't you think that this is as taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Chef is meant to deploy dozens, hundreds and thousands, but not one.

Comment: Yea that is true. But I'm using Vagrant to distribute a VM for local development. That VM is built with Chef. Why would I manually deploy something to the cloud that i've already automated with chef for a local VM?

Comment: @mailq Chef is meant to manage any number of servers that you want to manage. If you have small/modest needs, Opscode Hosted Chef is a free Chef Server that Opscode runs as a service. You can of course also use Chef Solo if that's your thing.

Comment: I disagree with mailq. Configuration Management is for managing one server, and also for managing 100,000.

Comment: My answer below might shed some light on this question - http://serverfault.com/questions/340603/bare-minimal-chef-provisioning-and-deployment/#answer-461302

Answer (score 6):

If you use chef-solo, you don't get to use knife. Knife is API client for the chef-server, with some extra utility sugar (like `knife rackspace server create` you've mentioned).

To configure server with chef-solo, you should copy your chef repo to the server, and run chef-solo there over ssh. There is no ready-made script or knife plugin that I know of that would do it automatically.

Command `knife rackspace server create` creates new Rackspace server, and then initializes it for chef-server that knife knows of by calling `knife bootstrap`. It won't work with chef-solo easily.

Technically, `knife bootstrap`, and thus `knife rackspace server create`, can be coerced to work with chef-solo by writing a custom bootstrap template that, instead of initializing chef-client, would download your chef repository and run chef-solo - see  `knife bootstrap --help`, its [wiki page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife+Bootstrap), or source for details. You can see example templates for installing chef-client [here](https://github.com/opscode/chef/tree/master/chef/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap). This is an advanced feature, though, and it's not very well documented.

If you don't want to handle complexity of installing and managing your own chef-server, you can use free layer of Opscode's Hosted Chef, which is Chef-server SAAS offering and is free up to three nodes. I'd recommend starting any serious work with server anyway - chef-solo is as good as a decent bootstrap shell script, no more, and you're missing out on many important/interesting features like search and data bags, which allow you to configure your servers in a data-driven way.

Comment: To clarify, chef-solo users *can* use knife, just not all the sub-commands that come with it by default. Specifically, the sub-commands that operate with a Chef Server :-).

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [knife-solo](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo) plugin, which can automatically install chef-solo on your remote server, upload your cookbooks onto it, and then run chef-solo. It basically automates what other folks who've answered this question have suggested doing.

Answer (score 2):

Before each chef-solo run, the cookbooks should be present on that target machine, either by transferring it (via ftp/scp) or pointing the cookbook_path to a network share .

If you want the cookbooks to be automatically downloaded, you would need to run a Chef Server. Whether you want to run your own chef server, or use a hosted one from OpsCode is up to you, but it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Barest, most basic way to get going with chef-solo.

- https://gist.github.com/e87e3d77d47a5151b8ee

Examples are contrived, and you should modify them.

More information about Chef Solo:

- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Solo

While Chef Solo is useful, it is really a limited way to use Chef. It doesn't expose information about the node outside of the node itself, so it cannot be used for dynamic discovery or data-driven infrastructure management nearly as easily as with Chef Server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a git project for that ;)

[The knife-solo git project](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo) should enable you to run `knife` in conjunction with `chef-solo` and allow you to do remote provisioning from your local dev environment to remote servers like this once you've got it configured locally and installed:

`knife solo cook ubuntu@10.0.0.201`